# Python 2.7.3 urllib2 urlopen response in binary

Tags: python-2.7, response, urllib2, urlencode, webservice-client

I am trying to read the response from a web service using Python 2.7.3. I do the request as follows:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
...
upgradedata = urllib.urlencode(upgradebody)
upgraderequest = urllib2.Request(UPGRADEURL, upgradedata)
upgraderequest.add_header('Accept', '*.*')
upgraderequest.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
upgraderequest.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate')

upgraderesponse = urllib2.urlopen(upgraderequest, timeout=5)
html = upgraderesponse.read();
```

All tutorials and samples says that I can just do:

```
print html
```

to see the response, but when I do that I get a lot of funny, unreadable characters. Obviously this is binary or something, so I googled and googled and finally found this page:
http://bugs.python.org/issue5419

My problem seems the same, but not sure how to solve this. The solution described in this page is to decode the binary string.

if I do:

```
print type(html)
```

it returns with:

```
<type 'str'>
```

and if I try to decode the string before I print it by doing this:

```
print html.decode('utf-8')
```

I get the following error:

```
'utf8' codec con't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

---

The actual code that I used to fix this is:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from StringIO import StringIO
import gzip
...
upgradedata = urllib.urlencode(upgradebody)
upgraderequest = urllib2.Request(UPGRADEURL, upgradedata)
upgraderequest.add_header('Accept', '*.*')
upgraderequest.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
upgraderequest.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')

upgraderesponse = urllib2.urlopen(upgraderequest, timeout=5)
html = None
if upgraderesponse.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
    stringbuffer = StringIO(upgraderesponse.read())
    gzipbuffer = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=stringbuffer)
    html = gzipbuffer.read()

print html
```

So, I removed deflate from my request header and use gzip to unzip the response. zlib may be a better solution? But at the moment this works fine for me. Thanks Burhan, for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have set:

```
upgraderequest.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate')
```

Chances are you are getting the compressed version of your content. You need to unzip it, try this:

```
import zlib

html = zlib.decompress(upgraderesponse.read())
```

Or, you can simply remove that header from your request.

Comment: Right you are... I actually fixed it using gzip